# The selector "relative-path" did not match any elements

Tags: javascript, angular

I am following the [component-relative paths angular documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-relative-paths.html).

Per the instructions, I am keeping my component ts and component html in the same directory. For the purpose of this question, that directory is **/app/components/first**

My component ts contains the following code, and is named First.component.ts

```
import {Component, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {MyService} from "../../service/MyService";
import {ValueObj} from "../../value/ValueObj";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'relative-path',
    templateUrl: 'First.component.html',
    providers: [MyService]
})

@Injectable()
export class FirstComponent {

    public valueObjs: ValueObj[];

    constructor(private _myService: MyService) {}

    getAllItems(): void {
        this._myService.getAllValueObjs().subscribe(
            data => this.valueObjs= data, error=> console.log(error),
            () => console.log("getting complete"));
    }
}
```

My First.component.html contains the following code:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="getAllItems()">
<label>Value Objects</label>
<button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
<hr>
<p style="color:red">{{error}}</p>
<h1>All Objects</h1>
<div *ngFor="let valueObj of valueObjs">{{valueObj.name}}</div>
```

I have looked at this solution, [The selector "my-app" did not match any elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35644123/the-selector-my-app-did-not-match-any-elements) , however, I do not find it applicable. My main.ts file only contains this:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

// start the application
const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

and has no reference to BrowserModule. I also looked at [why getting the error "The selector did not match any elements"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38565942/why-getting-the-error-the-selector-did-not-match-any-elements) , however, I have no boot.ts file to compare my values.

Lastly, I have looked at [Angular2 CLI build EXCEPTION : The selector "app-root" did not match any elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37840778/angular2-cli-build-exception-the-selector-app-root-did-not-match-any-element) , however, I have no reference to angular-universal in my packaging.json.

Any idea as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the same issue, the example is a bit confusing. The line:

```
selector: 'relative-path',
```

is just an example name of your component, it is not a command to use relative paths.

Simply adding the `moduleId` line will make relative paths work, so you can leave your `selector` as "first-component" or whatever you had before.

The error message is actually trying to say that the saying that the selector you have now ("relative-path") does not match what is in the index.html file. This only happens when you change the component that is in the `bootstrap` entry in app.module. If you had the same issue with a non-bootstrap module, you get a much clearer error message.

Comment: you are correct. While I gave up on trying to make relative paths work, your solution did help me ;) cheers